# Set own softKeyboard in android

Tags: android

I have a big problem. This is any possibility to set keyboard for one edit text? I mean I install other softkeyboard and I have this keyboard in settings. Now I want to click on checkbox and I want to see that keyboard which I was installed. How I can do that in code? This is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot programmatically control which keyboard is used by the user for security reasons.

At best, you could make a keyboard like View part of your app, and show/hide it in the onTouch() event for that on EditText.

Comment: hmmm. Maybe can I show window where user can set softkeyboard by yourself?

Comment: @edi233 You can use `startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS), 0);` for that, but that'll change the keyboard for the entire system.